# Type hint several different types for class parameter Pylance

Tags: python, class, subclass, pylance

What's the best way to type hint when the parameter can take several (15+) different classes?

I have a class `Path` with a parameter `action` that can take many different types of actions. Each action is derived from a base class `Action` and implements something specific to that child class compared to its siblings:

```
# path.py
class Path:
    def __init__(self, action)       # action: Any? Union[A,B,C,...]?
        # do some init stuff here
        
# actions.py
class Action:
    def __init__(self, ...)
        # do some init stuff here

class ActionA(Action):
    def __init__(self, ...)
        # do some init stuff here

class ActionB(Action):
    def __init__(self)
        # do some init stuff here


# plenty more Action subclasses
# in fact, in the future the list will probably keep growing
...
```

Most answers out there just mention `Union`, but that makes sense for just a few possible types. I don't imagine I should add a huge line on the parameters like `actions: Union[ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ..., ClassZ]`. In any case, when I tried, Pylance was saying `Argument to class must be a base class` and `Unknown type of base class, obscuring deriving type` or similar.

So then I thought of creating an `AllowedActions` class in a third file that just inherits from all the possible action classes. The idea is for `Path`'s `action=` to now take `AllowedAction` as a catch-all:

```
class AllowedAction(ActionA, ActionB, ActionC, ..., ActionZ):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I wouldn't mind then just tacking on `Action` subclasses to this `AllowedAction` declaration and in `Path` I could just say `action: AllowedAction`. However, now when I instantiate `Path` and add something to its `action` parameter like `Path(action=ActionA())`, I get that `Argument of type "ActionA" cannot be assigned to parameter "action" of type "AllowedAction"`. Obviously because the child class `ActionA` is not the same as the catch-all / subchild class `AllowedAction` but like wth.

This brings me to believe in `Path` I should just assign `action: Any`, but it seems like it kind of defeats the whole purpose of type hinting in the first place?

I don't know if I should be solving the problem this way or maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong and should be restructuring the inheritance or something. Any help?

Comment: You can give `Union` an alias: `AllowedAction = Union[ActionA, ActionB, ...]` and then your type hint becomes `action: AllowedAction`. Did you try that?

Comment: You may also want to look into [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype)

Comment: @blorgon Thanks! I was hoping there was some sort of aliasing for types, I should've google the term. I'll probably go with that, although `NewType` also seems like it could do the job. I haven't run the program yet with the aliasing but I think it answers my question so if you want to post below, I can accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not actually sure my suggestion solves your problem. As such, I'll refrain from posting an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Because all of your Action subclasses inherit from Action, you should be able to just do `def __init__(self, action:Action)` and the type checker will recognize the subclasses as being valid